# Convert Individual column searching (select inputs) to multi select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I am not sure but

I am trying to make it work and convert single inputs to multi select. But what the code shows is that it send a single value but when adding multiselect input it send a array. How do I make it work ?

https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html

Fiddle:- https://jsfiddle.net/43u2wno4/

```
.on('change', function() {
   var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this)val());
   column
   .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
   .draw();
});
```

Any suggestions ? or turnaround ?

Comment: use filter instad of search

Comment: I could do that. But in my case that is not feasible. The table that I have has like thousands of rows and the user would always want to see what the Multiple rows for multiple selection.